# NSMutableDictionary with nil as value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, unit-testing, nsmutabledictionary

I have a project at https://github.com/niklassaers/NJSNotificationCenter with so far only two unit tests. One of them runs, one of them runs 60% of the time. The remaining 40% of the time, it will fail because my NSMutableValue contains a nil value, even though I have never put in a nil value (nor should that be possible)

The problem arises here:

```
- (void) addObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector name:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject priority:(NSInteger)priority {
    NJSNotificationKey *key = [[NJSNotificationKey alloc] initWithObserver:observer name:aName object:anObject];
    NSLog(@"Key is: %p", key);
    key.priority = priority;
    NJSNotificationValue *value = [[NJSNotificationValue alloc] initWithSelector:aSelector];
    NSAssert(value, @"Value cannot be nil!");
    @synchronized(observers) {
        observers[key] = value;
        NSLog(@"Key: %p\tValue: %p\t%@", key, value, observers);
        if(observers[key] == nil)
            NSLog(@"This can't be!");
    }
}
```

I make a key, it is not nil, I make a value, it is not nil, I add it to my dictionary and get it back from the dictionary, but now it is nil! This makes no sense to me.

I have wrapped every access to observers (a local instance variable) in a @synchronized block just in case there was any other threading going on (there isn't).

Please check out my code (BSD license) and have a look at it, and help me understand how this can be. If you'd like, I'd love to pair program on this with you, I'm @niklassaers on Twitter

Comment: Are you actually instantiating a dictionary instance?

Comment: I doubt this piece of line : NJSNotificationValue *value = [[NJSNotificationValue alloc] initWithSelector:aSelector];

Comment: @ColinMorelli: I am, observers is not nil. If you have a look in the init method, it's instantiated there.

Comment: @yunas: Please tell me what you doubt about it? It doesn't return nil, and even at the time of the NSLog, it is still not nil, even though it is in the NSMutableDictionary observers

Comment: if its not can you please replace : observers[key] = value; with [observers setObject:value forKey:key] and try

Comment: @yunas: I did that, and it gives the same result. Please be my guest and clone the code from https://github.com/niklassaers/NJSNotificationCenter.git and try the test (it'll probably work 60% of the time, like it did when I replaced it with your code suggestion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't implemented hash.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000134-SW8

Keys must implement the hash and isEqual: methods because a dictionary
uses a hash table to organize its storage and to quickly access contained
objects
```

The dictionary is copying your key object and storing that - when it tried to lookup the original key object, it does not find it because the hash values do not match.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! :-) I hadn't noticed that part of the documentation, only that it had to conform to NSCopying. With the hash function in place, my tests run fine. :-) Thanks again!